# Hamming distance Matlab to Python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

Ok so I'm doing Hamming distance for two documents in k-NN approach. I'm trying to translate the Matlab code to Python, but I've been looking at it for hours and don't know what's causing the error.

Code in Matlab:

```
function [ Dist ] = hamming_distance( X,Xtrain )
% Function calculates Hamming distances of elements in set X from elements in set Xtrain. Distances of objects are returned as matrix Dist
% X - set of objects we are comparing N1xD
% Xtrain - set of objects to which X objects are compared N2xD
% Dist - matrix of distances between X and Xtrain objects N1xN2
% N1 - number of elements in X
% N2 - number of elements in Xtrain
% D - number of features (key words)

N1 = size(X,1);
N2 = size(Xtrain,1);
Dist = zeros(N1,N2);
D1 = size(X,2);
for i=1:N1
    for j=1:N2
        temp_matrix = xor(X(i,1:D1),Xtrain(j,1:D1));
        Dist(i,j) = sum(temp_matrix);
    end
end
end
```

This is what I wrote in Python so far:

```
def hamming_distance(X, X_train):
    """
    :param X: set of objects that are going to be compared N1xD
    :param X_train: set of objects compared against param X N2xD
    Functions calculates Hamming distances between all objects from set X  and all object from set X_train.
    Resulting distances are returned as matrices.
    :return: Distance matrix between objects X and X_train X i X_train N1xN2
    """
    N1 = X.shape[0]
    N2 = X_train.shape[0]
    hdist = np.zeros(shape =(N1, N2))
    D1 = X.shape[1]
    for i in range (1,N1):
        for j in range (1, N2):
            temp_matrix = np.logical_xor(X[i,1:D1], X_train[j, 1:D1])
            hdist[i, j] = np.sum(temp_matrix)
    return hdist
```

The error seems to be in the xor part of the Python code. I don't understand what could be wrong there; I tried putting it as `(X[i,1:D1]) ^ (X_train[j, 1:D1])` but it didn't change anything. I checked `logical_xor` function and it seems that I have correct inputs for the function. I don't understand where the error is coming from. Could it be because of different shapes of matrices? I'm confused when it comes to resizing them, should I change X and X_train to an array? I tried it once but it didn't help any.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\test.py", line 90, in test_hamming_distance
    out = hamming_distance(data['X'], data['X_train'])
  File "C:\...\content.py", line 28, in hamming_distance
    temp_matrix = np.logical_xor(X[i,1:D1], X_train[j, 1:D1])
  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py", line 559, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr + " not found")
AttributeError: logical_xor not found
```

I can't change the test.py, only the content.py. Test.py should be working fine, so I'm sure there's a mistake in my function. Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT:**
I have, on the top of my file:

```
import numpy as np
```

writing numpy instead of np didn't change anything. I get an error `'numpy wasn't defined'`.

Comment: That function doesn't exist in Numpy. That's all your error says

Comment: but? there exists a function numpy.logical_xor. I don't understand. Should I call it differently? I do have import numpy as np in my file. Should work I guess?

Comment: Show the code where you define `np`.  Is it the standard import `import numpy as np`?  Did you accidentally reuse the name `np`?

Comment: Your traceback shows `scipy\sparse\base.py`, not Numpy, though. And your versions of the libraries may not be for the documentation you've found

Comment: Ok, I edited the code. I have numpy imported as np and it worked for np.zeros, which is first in the code and didn't return any problems. And @cricket_007, I understand, thank you. Would changing my Python interpreter resolve this? Or maybe there's another way to use xor without all this hassle?

Comment: A [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I understand what you're saying but I did check it three times and highlighted all np's, I didn't use that name for anything else. All the code that I have you can see here, because in my content.py I only have this function so far + the import functions. I don't understand why is this happening :( Maybe there's a way to xor without numpy? Do you need the test.py excerpt as well?

Comment: See @TheBlackCat's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is because either `X` or `X_train` are scipy sparse matrices.  Scipy sparse matrices do not support logical operations yet, although work on this is [in-progress](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/5411).

The reason this error shows up in scipy rather than numpy when you are calling a numpy function is that `logical_xor` is a numpy ufunc, or "universal function".  Python classes that are intended to interact with numpy ufuncs can override the behavior of ufuncs, and scipy sparse matrices do that to avoid calling unsupported operations that would convert the array to a dense array and possibly eat up all your memory.

You would need to convert it to a dense array using, for example, `X.toarray()`.  If it is too big to fit into memory, you should use a package like `dask` or `bcolz` to handle the memory management for you.

Edit: scipy sparse matrices are not subclasses of ndarray.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, +1.  So the problem is numpy attempting to dispatch the call of `logical_xor` to a method on its arguments, but scipy's sparse matrices have no such method.  It would be nice if numpy generated a more useful error message in this case.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: Fixed